# How to select range of records in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, range

I am trying to select a range of records using a SQL Query:

```
SELECT COMPANY_ID as SEQ_NO, NULL URBAN_CODE
FROM (SELECT COMPANY_ID as SEQ_NO, NULL URBAN_CODE, ROWNUM num from COMPANY_TABLE)
WHERE num > 1 and num < 9
```

The error I keep getting is "URBAN_CODE": invalid identifier

I saw this solution from several SO pages but for some reason I keep getting this error.. can someone help? Thanks!

Comment: It's complaining about URBAN_CODE, not COMPANY_ID? Is that your actual query?

Comment: `NULL` is a keyword in SQL.  What exactly are you trying to do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If am not wrong you need to use `alias name` in outer query.

You cannot use `company_Id` in outer query because you have given a `alias name` in `sub-select` you need to use that.

```
SELECT SEQ_NO, URBAN_CODE
FROM (SELECT COMPANY_ID as SEQ_NO, NULL as URBAN_CODE, ROWNUM num from COMPANY_TABLE)
WHERE num > 1 and num < 9
```

Answer (score 3):

The code you showed can't complain about `URBAN_CODE`. But it will give you `ORA-00904: "COMPANY_ID": invalid identifier`, so maybe you've swapped the column names over in your post.

You're aliasing your `COMPANY_ID` column in your inline view, but then still trying to refer to the original unaliased name in the outer query. You can either use the alias, or define it later:

```
SELECT COMPANY_ID as SEQ_NO, NULL URBAN_CODE
FROM (SELECT COMPANY_ID, ROWNUM num from COMPANY_TABLE)
WHERE num > 1 and num < 9
```

or

```
SELECT SEQ_NO, URBAN_CODE
FROM (SELECT COMPANY_ID as SEQ_NO, NULL URBAN_CODE, ROWNUM num from COMPANY_TABLE)
WHERE num > 1 and num < 9
```

There's not much point having the `URBAN_CODE` in the inline view either if it's always null; doesn't really hurt, but you aren't using that generated (null) value in the outer query.

You're also using `ROWNUM` without doing any ordering, so your results will be indeterminate. You really need another layer of inline view:

```
SELECT COMPANY_ID as SEQ_NO, NULL as URBAN_CODE
FROM (
  SELECT COMPANY_ID, ROWNUM num
  FROM (
    SELECT COMPANY_ID
    FROM COMPANY_TABLE
    ORDER BY COMPANY_ID -- or whatever order you want to impose
  )
)
WHERE num > 1 and num < 9;
```